# ESLint config for unused var

Tags: eslint

Is it possible to fix all ESLint warning by CLI ?

I've try this, but don't fix all error (unused var for example) :

`eslint --fix src`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the old adage goes, "RTFM".

See: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#fixing-problems

---

`--fix`

This option instructs ESLint to **try to fix as many issues as possible**. The fixes are made to the actual files themselves and only the remaining unfixed issues are output. **Not all problems are fixable using this option**, and the option does not work in these situations:

1. This option throws an error when code is piped to ESLint.
2. This option has no effect on code that uses a processor, unless the
   processor opts into allowing autofixes.